# File Not found exception in opening a jar file after i make the jar file using command line arguments

Tags: java-me, jar, filenotfoundexception

The problem statement:

I have a J2ME app and i have a separate struts program running. The program automatically changes the source of the J2ME app an then builds it, pre-verify it, and then package it using command line arguments. To achieve all this i have used "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" in my program. Problem is that if i introduce a delay of one sec before the command for packaging is executed, the jar file is still formed BUT accessing the jar file using the command "DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));" gives me File Not found exception. "f" is the path to the jar file and i have checked it using "f.getCanonicalPath()" that its the right path.

I don know what the problem is. Please help me. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you waiting for the Process spawned by `Runtime.exec()` to complete before accessing the jar file? You can use `Process.waitFor()` for instance to halt the execution of your thread.